# Python function pointer with different arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have defined three functions.

```
def evaluate1(a, b):
    pass
```

```
def evaluate2(a, b):
    pass
```

```
def evaluate3(a, b, c):
    pass
```

What I want to do use a pointer to record which evaluate function I will use depending on the `test` inputs. The logic is as shown follows:

```
def test(a, b, c, d):
    # let evaluate_function records which evaluate function I will use
    if c > 1:
        evaluate_function = evaluate3 # not sure
    else:
       if d:
           evaluate_function = evaluate1
       else:
           evaluate_function = evaluate2

    # execute the evaluate function
    evaluate_function(a, b, ?)
```

However, since `evaluate3` has different arguments from `evaluate1` and `evaluate3`. How should I do? Thanks!

Comment: use `**kwargs` that will help you with dynamic signatures.

Comment: *Must* they have different arguments? If yes, could you use e.g. `functools.partial` or a `lambda` to wrap the one that takes three arguments such that the resulting `evaluate_function` always takes two arguments? If no, it would be easier if they didn't.

Comment: Use `*args` in the definitions

Comment: You can use default param in function declaration in c of evaluate3 if it can

Comment: Is the code in  all three functions different?

Comment: @Nishant yes, they are different

Answer (score 1):

You have come up with a good idea of using a 'function pointer' to select the function. But since you know which function you are selecting at the time, you could also bind up the params:

```
def test(a, b, c, d):
    # let evaluate_function records which evaluate function I will use
    if c > 1:
        evaluate_function = evaluate3 # not sure
        params = a,b,d
    else:
       if d:
           evaluate_function = evaluate1
           params = a,b
       else:
           evaluate_function = evaluate2
           params = a,c

    # execute the evaluate function
    evaluate_function(*params)
```

I'll leave it to you to properly select the `params`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call the evaluate functions directly instead of assigning them to a function as so. Makes it more readable

```
def evaluate1(a, b):
    print('evaluate1')

def evaluate2(a, b):
    print('evaluate2')

def evaluate3(a, b, c):
    print('evaluate3')

def test(a, b, c=None, d=None):
    # let evaluate_function records which evaluate function I will use
    if c and c > 1:
        evaluate3(a, b, c)
    else:
       if d:
           evaluate1(a, b)
       else:
           evaluate2(a, c)

test(1,2,c=0.1,d=1)
#evaluate1
test(1,2)
#evaluate2
test(1,2,3)
#evaluate3
```